# Save parent with children in one query ( children have null value reference for parent)

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, mapping

Good day. I can't save parent with children in same query. But children have null reference for parent...
Parent in my DB is table "food_in_the_cart" and model for it is here:

```
    public class FoodInTheCartModel
    {
        public virtual int ID { get; set; }
        public virtual ClientModel Client { get; set; }
        public virtual EstablishmentModel Stocked { get; set; }
        public virtual ProductModel DesirableProduct { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<CartAdditiveModel> Additives { get; set; } //children
        public virtual void AddAdditivesToTheCart(CartAdditiveModel a)
        {
            a.Cart = this;
            Additives.Add(a);
        }
        public FoodInTheCartModel()
        {
            this.Additives = new List<CartAdditiveModel>();
        }
    }
```

Mapping also:

```
public FoodInTheCartMap()
{
    Table("food_in_the_cart");

    Id(x => x.ID)
        .Column("id")
        .GeneratedBy.Native("food_in_the_cart_id_seq");

    References(x => x.Client)
        .Column("fk_id_client")
        .Not.Nullable()
        .Not.LazyLoad();

    References(x => x.DesirableProduct)
        .Column("fk_id_product")
        .Not.Nullable()
        .Not.LazyLoad();

    References(x => x.Stocked)
        .Column("fk_id_stock")


 .Not.Nullable()
            .Not.LazyLoad();

        HasMany(x => x.Additives)
            .Table("cart_additive")
            .Cascade.SaveUpdate()
            .Cascade.All()
            .Inverse()              
            .Not.LazyLoad();
    }
```

And child is **cart_additive**. Model of **cart_additive** is type of **CartAdditive** and has reference for model of **food_in_the_cart**, also mapping this reference is:

```
        References(x => x.Cart)
            .Column("fk_id_cart")                                      
            .Not.LazyLoad();
```

Type relationship between these two tables is one to many: **food_in_the_cart** has many **cart_additive**. Seems I tried everything for saving query for parent with children... But children still have null value for parent. How to make parent reference in child not null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed **Insert()** from has many in **FoodInTheCartMap** and and added **AsBug()** there, also allowed null values for fk of **food_in_the_cart** in **cart_additives** as for reference called Cart in model for this table. All works this way. Yay.